# Match height of image

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox layout that has 2 images side by side, one of them is cropped to 16x9 using percentage bottom padding

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}

.left, .right {
  height:100%;
}

.image_16x9_container{
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="left">
    <div class="img_wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/501/500">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <div class="img_wrapper">
      <div class="image_16x9_container">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

This is working correctly, but I would like to make the image on the left hand side match the height.

Anyone any ideas how I can achieve this using flexbox CSS or is this a job for jQuery?

Comment: I think you should remove some wrapper

Comment: to match the height of what?

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clearer. I want it to match the height of the image on the right

Comment: First, make sure you aren't complicating your requirement by forcing the solution to use *flexbox*.  Flexbox is a tool in a toolkit, it a solution for all problems.  Are you only going to have these `left` and `right` divs in `container` or will there be more items in the container?